# Dirac delta function as a product of Heaviside function and Exponent for large argument

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

Is is valid to say that

$\delta( x -t) = \lim_{A\to \infty} [A e^{-A (x-t)} \theta(x-t)]$

Here $A$, $x$ and $t$ are all positive.

Comment: isn't the RHS zero? and how are you defining $\delta$ outside an integral?

Comment: There shouldn't be an $A$ on the LHS, should there?

Comment: @GFauxPas - I am trying to use this as a way to simplify exponents and rewrite them with delta functions. For x > t, graphically $e^{A(x-t)}\theta(x-t) \to \delta(A(x-t))$ for large A

Comment: @md2perpe I edited it to make factors of A consistent

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. I will show it for $t=0$. The general case is just a translation of this.

Take $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Then we have
$$
\langle A e^{-Ax} \theta(x),  \phi(x) \rangle
= \int A e^{-Ax} \theta(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx
= \{ y = Ax \}
= \int_0^\infty e^{-y} \, \phi(y/A) \, dy \\
\to \int_0^\infty e^{-y} \, \phi(0) \, dy
= \int_0^\infty e^{-y} \, dy \, \phi(0)
= \phi(0)
= \langle \delta(x), \phi(x) \rangle
$$
as $A \to \infty$.

This shows that 
$$\lim_{A \to \infty} A e^{-Ax} \theta(x) = \delta(x).$$

Comment: Are you taking the limit inside or outside the integral sign?

Comment: @GFauxPas. Outside, but it can be moved inside since the integrand is very nice.